# Navigation Disappearing in Chrome after scrolling and clicking

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, navigation

I am working on a small website for an Android App I'm releasing, but I have a small problem that I can't seem to find the answer to.

In Firefox, everything works properly but when you scroll and then click on a nav link (simply using an id to move down the page) but on Chrome, the navigation disappears until you scroll some more.

The website is up at
[www.ioudebtcalculator.com](http://www.ioudebtcalculator.com)

These are the only styles I have applied:

```
#navBar {
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13pt;
    height:70px;
}
```

Edit: I have since removed the position fixed from the navBar on the website so you will no longer see the problem there.  The problem has not yet been solved.

You can easily add position fixed to the navBar element using Developer Tools or any other equivalent tool to see the problem.

Comment: There's a typo in your viewport statement. It should be "initial-scale" not "inital-scale". Not sure whether it's related but you should correct that and check.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have updated with the correct spelling, but the problem seems to be continuing.

Comment: see Matthew R's answer below. Setting `top: 0;` should do it. Or try `position: absolute; top: 0;` if there's a glitch

Comment: It doesn't appear to fix it, and there is no way I can have position absolute and fixed at the same time.

Comment: Then where on earth can we see your problem now ? :|

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it works for me when adding this to your navbar css

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

making it

```
#navBar {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14pt;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 2.5px 20px #000;
}
```

Comment: This is what did it. I have taken out position:fixed for now because of mobile devices, but this solved it for Chrome.

Comment: Dear god. I have been pounding my head against a bug where in chrome vertical scrolling caused an element to intermittently appear/disappear throughout the page. I was tearing my face off over this in frustration.
THANK YOU.

Answer (score 5):

It might be benefitial to use a scroll:

This will make it more userfriendly because it's gracefull and the problem (I imagine) is in the fact that Chrome doesn't register the position change because of the current method.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
     }, 2000);
 });
```

Comment: I have yet to try this, because of adding extra JavaScript, but this may be the only solution.  If this is the solution, then Chrome has some problem with position fixed...

Comment: I think it has a problem with the position changing with scripts.

Comment: Seconding @SMillerNL here. Opera Mobile used to have a similar problem with `position: fixed;`. It has to do with the way that it redraws the page after scrolling. You can even get it to redraw buttons with defined `:hover` states by mousing over them after scrolling. Forcing the engine to redraw by using jQuery's `animate()` may very well be your best bet. You can always shorten the animation to make it behave similarly to the current state.

Comment: This is probably what I'm eventually going to go with, but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for because of the added JavaScript.  I have upvoted you though, and thanks for trying.

Answer (score 3):

Please replace your css using below code

```
    nav {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 115px !important;
        float: left;
        height: 70px;
        margin-left: 10%;
        width: 40%;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no clue what's going wrong.  But I'm going to throw out my best guess since nobody's answered yet.

The following looks like a good candidate for screwy behavior:

```
function switchTabs(e) {
    $('a#currentTab').removeAttr('id');
    $(e).children('a').attr('id','currentTab');
}
```

`id` is a property not an attribute, and adding and removing ids seems like a really bad idea because that's how elements in the DOM are uniquely identified.  That's something I wouldn't mess around with.  Plus it's easy to recreate the desired functionality with classes:

```
function switchTabs(e) {
    $('a.currentTab').removeClass('currentTab');
    $(e).children('a').addClass('currentTab');
}
```

Maybe I got lucky?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me.  I have made those changes and pushed them up to the server, if you would like to continue trying to help.  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `top: 0` to your element. That will align it to the top of the page no matter what. You may need to add padding to the top of the content wrapper so that it is never covered by the nav.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just added two things both in Chrome and Firefox and it was working well. I clicked the link and scrolled a bit too, the nav stays as its expected.

```
For #navBar
position: fixed;

For #wrapper
padding-top: 70px;
```